# Instance of Object error?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, gridview, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have one GridControl in which I inserted, modified directly to the database.

I have several fields directly connected to a table `Patient` and one of my gridcontrol field is the `id` that was `especielistas 1` `Table`Specialist`which has a 1:1 Relationship`Esp-> MuchosPacientes`and this field shows you all`ID specialists`and lets me do the main functions. But to eliminate me says no sender == null`, but implement the same code but for 1 event `KeyDown` and does it perfectly removed and `sender != null` which can be:

```
private void gridControl1_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(
        object sender,
         NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
{           
    if (e.Button.ButtonType == NavigatorButtonType.Edit 
        || e.Button.ButtonType == NavigatorButtonType.EndEdit)
    {
        ColumnView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;
        view.CloseEditor();

        if (view.UpdateCurrentRow())
        {
            pacienteTableAdapter.Update(dBDataSet);
        }
    }
    else if (e.Button.ButtonType == NavigatorButtonType.Remove)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show("Desea eliminar?", "Confirmación", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
            return;

        GridView view = sender as GridView;   //AQUI ES EL ERROR
        view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
        pacienteTableAdapter.Update(dBDataSet);

    }           
}

private void gridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Desea eliminar?", "Confirmación", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
            return;

        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
        pacienteTableAdapter.Update(dBDataSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please edit it to clarify - in particular, what are you actually *asking*?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use "gridView1" instead of "view" (cast from "sender")?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in the `gridView1_KeyDown` event the sender is `gridView1` so when you cast to a GridView - all is well.

In `gridControl1_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick` event your sender is `gridControl1`, thus, when you cast from sender you get `null`.

Try either casting to GridControl and then getting Views or renaming `gridView1` to a more explanatory name and referencing it directly.